# Error approving edit suggestions

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, error-message

I tried to approve an edit by @Kissaki and got the too many votes error, then I tried again on a different post, and it succeeded.

I think the problem has something to do with the tag-wiki edit approvals.

[image: Error approving edit]

Comment: [Also, that post is still in the queue. (Someone fix that please)](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?pagesize=15&filter=day)

Comment: It's 20 minutes old.  I feel that ins unacceptable.  Does that seem too long for anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure I fixed this issue ....

Comment: I don't seem to have this same issue anymore.  Thanks.